# ios project build failing and giving below error

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework: No such file or directory

Have reinstall cocoapods, pods but nothing worked.Please let me know incase anyone come across this type of issue. It would be helpful.Thanks